# Reloading a page from selecting a taxonomy term from a views filter

Tags: views, panels

### general

I have a book containing docs for multiple versions of software.

I want the pages of those books to be searchable and sorted per version.

### specifically

I have a node override provided my panels of a certain content type.

One of those panels is a view displaying the content type that has been tagged with a taxonomy term.

How can I

1. Create an exposed filter that provides a dropdown selection of
   terms, in this case, version numbers?

and

2. Have the page reload the view after a new term, in this case, the
   version number, is selected and then submitted via a submit button?

This would preferably be done with contrib modules.

Answer (score 1):

No need for contrib modules: it's all in Views.

So firstly you'll need to add a Filter criteria in your View.

1. *Add*
2. Select the term field (Topic in my case)
3. Configure extra settings: *Dropdown*
4. Configure filter criterion: *Expose this filter to vistors*

Secondly you'll need to enable AJAX submits.

1. *Advanced > Other > Use AJAX > Yes*

[image]

There are a couple of contrib modules that may be useful however.

- [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) for very long select lists
- [Better exposed filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) if Select lists aren't good in your case

Comment: How can I get this to refresh the node, which is in another panel? This is a node override page and the version select box(a list of taxonomy terms) is in the sidebar. I need it to load the proper node(tagged with a version term), which is the main part of the page, when a different version(a taxonomy term) is selected from the view filter in the sidebar. Make any sense? @Queenvictoria

Comment: You can use the "Exposed form in block: Yes" and place the block elsewhere in the Panels page.